# Trimming first characters from a string regex

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

So I have the following pattern:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('000755490975','[^1-9]+\0') REGEX_RESULT FROM DUAL
```

And I'm trying to cut the first zeros until the first digit greater than zero, it works in one case cause this is the result:

> 755490975

But if the first char is a zero, is showing that in the result, so supposing to have this:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('0755490975','[^1-9]+\0') REGEX_RESULT FROM DUAL
```

The result is:

> 0755490975

I also debugged on https://regex101.com/ but I couldn't find anything useful.
What is wrong on my regex?

Comment: Are you looking for `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('0755490975','^0+', '') AS REGEX_RESULT FROM DUAL`? Remove one or more zeros from the start of string?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes it is! Can you please explain it?

Comment: Doesn't `ltrim(<your string>, '0')` work for you?

Comment: @Boneist Yes, it works the same, I actually don't know on performance side if it's impacting more or less compared to the other method suggested.

Comment: The regex functions are generally slower than simpler ones like `ltrim`.

Comment: Alright then, I think this is the correct answer to the question, but I also think that  doesn't matter if the result is being reached. Thanks for the explanation again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `[^1-9]+\0` pattern is parsed as `[^1-9]+0` - any 1 or more chars other than a digit from `1` to `9` (so, any letters, punctuation, `0`, etc.) followed with a `0` char. So, all non `1-9` chars followed with `0` are removed anywhere in the input string.

Note that `\0` is not throwing an error because the POSIX regex standard allows backreferences from `1` to `9`, there is no zeroth backreference. So, it is treated as if it were an escaped "regular" (non-special) char. And they are matched as if they were not escaped, as is.

You may use

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('0755490975','^0+', '') AS REGEX_RESULT FROM DUAL
```

The regex is

- `^` - start of string
- `0+` - 1 or more zeros

See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/cRPt1m/1).

[Online Oracle demo](http://rextester.com/NDGLW76268):

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the complete explanation! :)